# spark convert Vector[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to calculate the distance between the row in a dataframe and a vector( `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`).

I plan to do anomaly detection with K-Means algorithm, so I got the center id which is a Vector then I can calculate the distance with row in a dataframe, but I got below error:

```
Vectors.sqdist(v1,centerid)
<console>:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

How to convert the `Vector[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` to `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`?

Comment: please share your codes too

Answer (score 0):

You can use VectorAssembler to convert your Row to a features Vector. Try this:

```
  val df: DataFrame = ???

  val vector = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("yourInputColumns")).setOutputCol("features")

  vector.transform(df)
```

As output you will get a Dataframe with one column with the type
 **org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector**